# How to set write permission with Samba?

Tags: permissions, samba, configuration

I've searched for about 6 hours now trying to setup my samba (version 4.6.7) server, but I'm stuck where I can't have my users create files with `-rw-rw----`
 permissions.

First, let me explain my ultimate goal (**maybe there are simpler solutions than what I am currently working on, if so tell me**): I want to have 1 share that is available without authentication, 1 share only accessible by user "foo", and 1 share only accessible by user "bar".

Here's what I have done so far:
I have created UNIX users "main", "foo", and "bar", and they are all in the UNIX group "smbusers". I have also added the user "nobody" to the group "smbusers". I have then created shares in `/tmp/testshare`, with these permissions:

```
> ls -la /tmp/testshare
drwxrws---  5 main smbusers 4096 Dec 24 17:29 .
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root     4096 Dec 24 17:28 ..
drwxrws---  2 main smbusers 4096 Dec 24 17:29 bar
drwxrws---  2 main smbusers 4096 Dec 24 17:29 foo
drwxrws---  2 main smbusers 4096 Dec 24 17:28 Public
```

Here are my configs in `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    os level = 20
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    writeable = yes
    security = user
    map to guest = bad password
    force user = main
    force group = smbusers
    create mask = 0660
    force create mode = 0660
    directory mask = 0770
    force directory mode = 0770
    encrypt passwords = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    pam password change = yes
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    max log size = 1000
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    dns proxy = no
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY

[Public]
    path = /tmp/testshare/public
    guest ok = yes

[bar]
    path = /tmp/testshare/bar
    valid users = bar

[foo]
    path = /tmp/testshare/foo
    valid users = foo
```

**UPDATE**: Now, from Windows, if I create files as a guest (aka "nobody:nogroup"), the files are attributed the correct permissions as I have set them, but as soon as I connect to any account, "foo" or "bar", it refuses to set the write permissions to the group (or even to anybody, as I have tried later with `create mask = 0222`):

```
#I created these two without authenticating myself
> ls -lA /tmp/testshare/public
-rw-rw---- 1 main smbusers    0 Dec 24 19:43 New Text Document.txt
drwxrwx--- 2 main smbusers 4096 Dec 24 19:43 New Folder

#I created these two after I succesfully authenticated myself as "foo".
> ls -lA /tmp/testshare/public
-rw-r----- 1 main smbusers    0 Dec 24 19:43 New Text Document.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 main smbusers 4096 Dec 24 19:43 New Folder
```

As you can see, once I authenticated myself, it refuses to give write permission to the group, therefore I can't edit files from Windows.

**What would I need to change to make it work as expected? I am suspecting the accounts are not correctly configured but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.**

Note: I should also mention that the `testshare` folder I was using for my tests is on the drive running my *Ubuntu Server 17.10*, and my real setup is going to use an external drive mounted in ntfs-3g.

**UPDATE2**: I have tried the same setup on my external drive mounted in ntfs-3g, and everything works as expected. Although I am still curious to see why it was not working in my `/tmp/testshare` folder...

Comment: Well if its going to be ntfs you really don't have to worry about this .. since ntfs doesn't use Linux permissions. but I would try and move the `force user = main, force group = smbusers, create mask = 0660, force create mode = 0660, directory mask = 0770 and force directory mode = 0770` under the `[Public], [bar] and [foo]` segments. and restart samba

Comment: I have tried what you suggested me, but the same problem occured. I did some more testing, and i found out that this strange behavior only happens when I am authenticated. If i connect to my public share as a guest, the correct permissions get assigned. (I updated my post to include this)